# How to write templated factory function for both std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, smart-pointers

I often write factory which have a signature similar to the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<AbstractType> createUnique(IDType id);
std::shared_ptr<AbstractType> createShared(IDType id);
```

Where the former would do something like:

```
switch (id)
{
case kID1:
    return std::make_unique<Type1>();
}
```

And the latter

```
switch (id)
{
case kID1:
    return std::make_shared<Type1>();
}
```

Well, the only different between the two functions is the "make" function used (`make_shared` or `make_unique`) and the return type (`shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`).  This leads to code duplication.

I am wondering how I could write a templated `create` function which accepts the pointer type and "make" function type and uses those instead.  Something like:

```
template <typename PTR, typename MAKE>
PTR create(IDType id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
    case kID1:
        return MAKE<Type1>();
    }
}
```

I am aware that the above is not valid code.

Also, I am aware that a `std::shared_ptr` could be created from an `std::unique_ptr` and visa versa, but I this factory would be used in different applications where one might use the `shared_ptr` and the other might use the `unique_ptr`.  This way, the code is re-usable but also effecienct for the particular use-case.

Comment: In most cases you can just provide `std::unique_ptr<AbstractType> createUnique(IDType id);` as the return value is implicitly convertible to `std::shared_ptr<AbstractType>`. Or you can implement `createShared(IDType id)` as `return createUnique(id);`. It is a performance hit as it avoids the `make_shared` allocation optimization but in many cases this is minor compared to the gain in simplicity.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The only qualm I have with this method is the additional heap allocation required.  In my application, I ideally want the heap allocations to be as minimal as possible.  But yes, I agree this is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: I would not care about code duplication if factory is so simple like in posted code. If factory is more complex then it is possible to create a template which can address this issue.

Comment: @MarekR Agreed.  My real code would be a factory that can create tens of different classes, so the duplication is not so trivial.

Comment: It depends on how you need to identify the ownership. If your factory can tell which pointer type it needs, the rest is some meta-programming game. The final solution depends on how you notify your template of the intended pointer type. We need more clarification. Does a compile-time boolean flag work, or should you get the info from a function argument?

Answer (score 6):

My advice, only have a single return type of `std::unique_ptr<AbstractType>`.  If you do that then you can use the function with `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` like

```
auto my_ptr = createInterface(id);
```

which has `my_ptr` being a `unique_ptr` or

```
std::shared_ptr<AbstractType> my_ptr = createInterface(id);
```

and now the returned `unique_ptr` is converted into a `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid loosing use of `std::make_shared` which optimizes use of memory, I would approach this issue this way:

```cpp
class AbstractType {
public:
    virtual ~AbstractType() = default;

    virtual int f() const = 0;
};

class Foo : public AbstractType {
public:
    int f() const override
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

class Bar : public AbstractType {
public:
    int f() const override
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

enum class IDType {
    Foo,
    Bar,
};

class Factory {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<AbstractType> createUnique(IDType id);
    std::shared_ptr<AbstractType> createShared(IDType id);

private:
    template <typename MakePtr>
    auto createUniversal(IDType id);
};

//======================
class WrapMakeUnique {
public:
    template <typename Base, typename T, typename... Args>
    static auto make(Args... args) -> std::unique_ptr<Base>
    {
        return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

class WrapMakeShared {
public:
    template <typename Base, typename T, typename... Args>
    static auto make(Args... args) -> std::shared_ptr<Base>
    {
        return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template <typename MakePtr>
auto Factory::createUniversal(IDType id)
{
    switch (id) {
    case IDType::Foo:
        return MakePtr::template make<AbstractType, Foo>();
    case IDType::Bar:
        return MakePtr::template make<AbstractType, Bar>();
    }
    throw std::invalid_argument { "IDType out of range" };
}

std::unique_ptr<AbstractType> Factory::createUnique(IDType id)
{
    return createUniversal<WrapMakeUnique>(id);
}

std::shared_ptr<AbstractType> Factory::createShared(IDType id)
{
    return createUniversal<WrapMakeShared>(id);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9f1ddj9zo

Comment: I would get rid of the `Base` parameter and trailing return type on the `make()` methods, as `(unique|shared)_ptr<T>` are implicitly convertible to `(unique|shared)_ptr<Base>`

Answer (score 1):

Your generic factory method is very close:

```
template <typename PTR, typename MAKE>
PTR create(IDType id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
    case kID1:
        return MAKE<Type1>();
    }
}
```

The key parts you're missing appear to be that (1) `MAKE` is a type, so `MAKE<Type1>()` is a syntax we'll probably want to skip, and (B) how to use it.

The ideal way to use it is with two factory classes:

```
template<class Base>
struct make_unique_factory {
    using PTR = std::unique_ptr<Base>;
    template<class Derived, class... Args>
    PTR create(Args&&... args) const 
    {return std::make_unique<Derived>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);}
};

template<class Base>
struct make_shared_factory {
    using PTR = std::shared_ptr<Base>;
    template<class Derived, class... Args>
    PTR create(Args&&... args) const 
    {return std::make_shared<Derived>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);}
};
```

(We use classes and not methods so that the compiler has an easier time inlining.  Method parameters are harder to inline)

And then use is similar to what you had:

```
template <typename MAKE>
auto create(IDType id) -> typename MAKE::PTR
{
    switch (id)
    {
    case kID1:
        return MAKE{}.template create<Type1>();
    }
}

std::unique_ptr<AbstractType> createUnique(IDType id) {
    return create<make_unique_factory<AbstractType>>(id);
}

std::shared_ptr<AbstractType> createShared(IDType id) {
    return create<make_shared_factory<AbstractType>>(id);
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc3d5d2431a0b0da

The reason you had trouble is probably this line:

`MAKE{}.template create<Type1>()`

So I'll break that down.  `MAKE{}` constructs an instance of the `MAKE` class.  Then, we call the `create<Type1>()` method on that instance.  However, when the compiler is compiling this `create()` method, it doesn't yet know what `MAKE` is, so doesn't know that its `create()` method is a template method. So annoyingly, we have to tell it explicitly that this method is a template method, leading to `MAKE{}.template create<Type1>()`.

Comment: I now realize I misread MarekR's answer, and it is fundamentally the same as mine.